# Laravel Own ServiceProvider Client Call Type error: Argument 1 passed to ... must be an instance of

Tags: php, laravel

I want to swap out my client call or better i try to make a wrapper around [this package](https://github.com/LeadCommerceDE/shopware-sdk), so i dont have to write this everytime, so i made a new ServiceProvider which should call

```
// Create a new client, 
// so i dont have to type this in every Method
$client = new ShopwareClient('url', 'user', 'api_key');
```

on every request i make.

```
// Later after the Client is called i can make a Request
return $client->getArticleQuery()->findAll();
```

**SwapiServiceProvider**

```
<?php

namespace Chris\Swapi;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use LeadCommerce\Shopware\SDK\ShopwareClient;

class SwapiServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Perform post-registration booting of services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Register any package services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(ShopwareClient::class, function () {
            return new ShopwareClient(
                    env('SHOPWARE_URL'),
                    env('SHOPWARE_USER'),
                    env('SHOPWARE_KEY')
                );
        });
    }
}
```

My Class

```
...
use LeadCommerce\Shopware\SDK\ShopwareClient as Shopware;

class Swapi
{
    public function fetchAllArticles(Shopware $shopware)
    {
        return $shopware->getArticleQuery()->findAll();
    }
}
```

**Testing**

I just call it in my routes.php for testing

```
use Chris\Swapi\Swapi;

Route::get('swapi', function () {
    // Since this is a package i also made the Facade
    return Swapi::fetchAllArticles();
});
```

But i get everytime the error

> FatalThrowableError in Swapi.php line 18: Type error: Argument 1
>   passed to Chris\Swapi\Swapi::fetchAllArticles() must be an instance of
>   LeadCommerce\Shopware\SDK\ShopwareClient, none given, called in
>   /Users/chris/Desktop/code/swapi/app/Http/routes.php on line 7

So i am asking why this

```
return new ShopwareClient(
   env('SHOPWARE_URL'),
   env('SHOPWARE_USER'),
   env('SHOPWARE_KEY')
);
```

is not called everytime i call a method e.g `$shopware->getArticleQuery()->findAll();`
Does anyone know why?

Comment: The constructor **is** called - that has nothing to do with your error. the **method** `fetchAllArticles` requires an instance of `Shopware` to be passed as an argument, you dont do that: `return Swapi::fetchAllArticles(); //<-- no args passes`

Comment: Thats the Problem, i dont need to pass any arguments. The Client seems not to be called if you have a look at the actual package: https://github.com/LeadCommerceDE/shopware-sdk

So what should i do now ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be some confusion here about Laravel's IoC.  When you use `return Swapi::fetchAllArticles();`, Laravel doesn't know what you are doing because you haven't used the container to build out the `Swapi` class (even though you have registered one with the container) nor do you have a facade built to access it in that manner.  Otherwise PHP is going to complain because your function isn't `static`.

I just wrote this code and verified that it works as far as Laravel putting it all together.

In my service provider, my register function was this...

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('swapi', function($app) {
        return new SwapiRepository(
            new ShopwareClient(
                env('SHOPWARE_URL'),
                env('SHOPWARE_USER'),
                env('SHOPWARE_KEY')
            )
        );
    });
}
```

Keep in mind, `swapi` is really just a key the container will use to find the actual class.  There's no need to pass in the entire qualified class name when you can keep it simple and easy.

My `SwapiRepository` which is really the wrapper for the Shopware SDK.

```
use LeadCommerce\Shopware\SDK\ShopwareClient;

class SwapiRepository
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct(ShopwareClient $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function fetchAllArticles()
    {
        return $this->client->getArticleQuery()->findAll();
    }
}
```

At this point, you are basically done.  Just add `App\Providers\SwapiServiceProvider::class,` in the `providers` array (which you probably have done already) in `app/config.php` and use your wrapper like so...

```
$swapi = app('swapi');
$swapi->fetchAllArticles();
```

Or you can have Laravel inject it into other classes as long as Laravel is building said class.

If you want to build out a facade for this to save yourself a line of code each time you want to use this or for snytactical sugar...

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Swapi extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'swapi'; }
}
```

Make sure to update your `aliases` array in `app/config.php` so that it contains `'Swapi' => App\Repositories\Swapi::class,`

And finally you should be able to use it like so...

```
Swapi::fetchAllArticles();
```

Please note your namespaces are different than mine so you may need to replace mine with yours.  You should also now be able to easily inject `Swapi` into other classes and even method injected into your controllers where needed.

Just remember if you do that though, make sure you are grabbing instances of those classes from Laravel's service container using the `app()` function.  If you try to build them out yourself using `new SomeClass`, then you have the responsibility of injecting any dependencies yourself.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. One last Question: If i use the Facade, PHPStorm does not recognizes the Methods of the Repository since it seems it should be in the Swapi.php Class. How would i go about this since the Methods are in the Repository and not in the Swapi.php Class. Thanks again so much for your help.

Is it possible to have a standalone SwapiFacade.php? But how would i "load" this Facade?

Comment: Use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper and PHPStorm will start recognizing the facades.